# Cast from 'Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>.Keys?' to unrelated type '[Any]' always fails

Tags: swift, dictionary

i am getting this warning,

Cast from 'Dictionary.Keys?' to unrelated type '[Any]' always fails

i have no idea how to fix this please help me out

```
class func appendPram(_ url: String?, paramDict dict: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> String? {
        var dict = dict
        var returnPath = "\(url ?? "")?"
        let keyArray = dict?.keys as? [Any]
        for key: String? in keyArray as? [String?] ?? [] {
            if (keyArray as NSArray?)?.index(of: key ?? "") == 0 || (keyArray as NSArray?)?.index(of: key ?? "") == keyArray?.count {
                if let aKey = dict?[key!] {
                    returnPath = "\(returnPath)\(key ?? "")=\(aKey)"
                }
            } else {
                if let aKey = dict?[key!] {
                    returnPath = "\(returnPath)&\(key ?? "")=\(aKey)"
                }
            }
        }
        return returnPath
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason every single variable has to be optional? Also, why are you passing a URL as a `String` instead of a `URL`?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka, i am using optional to keep code more secure and i have taken url as String in another function

Comment: Wow, 28 question marks in 12 lines of code. For example `for key: String? in keyArray`. A dictionary key can never ever be `nil` by definition. What is this function supposed to do? Consider that a dictionary is unordered so the order of the key array can be different. And the `if let aKey` (actually **`aValue`**) expressions are pointless. If there is a key then it's guaranteed that there is also a value.

Comment: @ vadian i removed unnecessary optional ?, thnx it is working

Answer (score 6):

```
let keyArray = dict?.keys as? [Any]
```

The conversion here is not possible because `dict.keys` is of type `[AnyHashable: Any].Keys`. You are trying to cast that type to an array. Since they are not related at all, the compiler warns you that this will always fail.

Most likely, you meant to convert to `[AnyHashable]`

One correct way of converting from `[AnyHashable: Any].Keys` to `[AnyHashable]` is to use the `Array.init(Sequence)` initializer:

```
 let keyArray = dict.map { Array($0.keys) }
```

Comment: it is working for me thank you, but i have a question, how does the dict.map{Array($0.keys)} function works,please explain

Comment: @PankajChahakar the `map` method is used here because `dict` is optional. It applies the closure to the optional if the optional is not nil, or nil if the optional is nil.

Answer (score 0):

@Sweeper explained clearly. In your case I think this will help

```
let keyArray = dict["key"] as? [String]
```